# Convert String to java.sql.Time and java.sql.Time to Double

Tags: java, java-time

I have a `String` "02:30" for example. I want to convert it to `java.sql.Time`, from `java.sql.Time` then convert it again to `double`, so be 2.5 hours ..... What is the best solution for it ???

Comment: The best solution is to store a time as a [`Time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) and a duration as a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html). Not a `String`. Not a `double`.

Comment: Time.valueOf(String) might help to create a Time from a String

Comment: So if I understand correctly, 02:30 does not mean 2:30 am, but 2 hours 30 minutes? Also if I understand correctly the SQL `TIME` datatype that `Time`  was meant to be used with, is for clock times like 2:30 am, so I am suspecting your use may be unorthodox?

Comment: @yohann.martineau Time.valueOf(String) only works for "hh:mm:ss" format, and throws IllegalArgumentException for "02:30".

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou, so append ":00" first?

Comment: To get a `double` from a `Time`, I’d first use `myTime.getTime()` to get the time in milliseconds, then divide by the number of millis in an hour. Remember to convert to `double` first, or the remainder in the division would be lost (you would get 2 hours instead af 2.5).

Answer (score 1):

This is your code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     String res="02:30";
      Time tm=new Time(Integer.valueOf(res.split(":")[0]), Integer.valueOf(res.split(":")[1]), 0);
      Double dbl=new Double(tm.getHours()+Math.floor(tm.getMinutes()*100/60)/100);
      System.out.println(dbl.toString());
}
```

**Note** The constructor Time(int, int, int) is deprecated, we should use `long` instead.